# Windows 8 Legacy BIOS mode and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS dual boot

Tags: dual-boot

I have fresh installed Windows 8 on my laptop and I want to dual boot it with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS(64 bit).

My BIOS Mode is Legacy.

I want to know is their any issues with dual booting, I just want to know before preceding to install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I have had dual-boot setup before and I have never had a issue. You should be perfectly fine unless you accidentally select the wrong partition when installing Ubuntu and erase Win8!!!